# Create BitmapFrame asynchronously in an async method

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, bitmapframe

Anyone knows how to create `BitmapFrame` asynchronously in WPF?

I want to batch print XAML `Image` element whose `Source` property is set code behind. Here `LogoImageUrl` is the URL of the web image I want to load asynchronously.

```cs
LogoImage.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(LogoImageUrl));
```

Can I create an `async` method like this:

```cs
public async Task<BitmapFrame> GetBitmapFrame(Uri uri)
{
    await ... // What to be awaited?

    return BitmapFrame.Create(uri);
}
```

...so I can use that method in a `try` block and then print it in `finally` block?

Comment: You can use [IsAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.isasync(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the binding to achieve that.

Comment: Are your loading local or remote (web) image files?

Comment: @Clemens I want to load web image.

Comment: Does it really have to be a BitmapFrame?

Comment: @Clemens Sorry, but yeah, I have to use BitmapFrame.

Comment: Hint: The `Freeze` / `AsFrozen` make ImageSource thread-safe.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Another hint: `BitmapFrame.Create(stream, ..., BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad)` already returns a frozen BitmapFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should asynchronously download the web image and create a BitmapFrame from the downloaded buffer:

```
public async Task<BitmapFrame> GetBitmapFrame(Uri uri)
{
    var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    var buffer = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(uri);

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
    {
        return BitmapFrame.Create(
            stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
    }
}
```

---

Since the `BitmapFrame.Create` call in the above example return a frozen BitmapFrame, you may also create the BitmapFrame asynchronously (although I doubt it's necessary).

```
public async Task<BitmapFrame> GetBitmapFrame(Uri uri)
{
    var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    var buffer = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(uri);

    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
        {
            return BitmapFrame.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Duh, how can I not think of HttpClient... Thanks, it works!